# how to bind multi-variables and slice variable at the same time in go when excute mysql update sql stament like update .. where .. in?

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I have some string variables and a slice variable as SQL params in golang, but got errors `corresponding parameter is non-variadic` returned when I attempt to execute.
so how can I bind these variables in this case?

**mysql connector**: go-sql-driver/mysql
**fake code**:

```golang
func UpdateTblNm (foo, baz string, bar int, pars []string) error {
    stmt:= `update tbl_nm set foo=?, bar=? where baz=? and par in (?`+ strings.Repeat(", ?", len(pars)-1) + `)`
    if _, err := tx.Exec(stmt, foo, bar, baz, pars...); err!=nil {
        return err
    }
    ... ...
}
```

im new guy of gopher..
Hoping your help, thx

Comment: Does that even compile? To pass args to `tx.Exec(string,...interface{})`, you should create an `args:=[]interface{}{ all known params }`, then append all elements of []string in a for loop, and pass  `args...`.

Comment: thx, Im trying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a fixed number of arguments and a variadic one, you have to collect them all into an array, and pass them because go variadics cannot deal with what you're trying to do:

```
args:=[]interface{}{foo,baz,bar}
for _,x:=range pars {
  args=append(args,x)
}
tx.Exec(stmt,args...)
```

Comment: If that's the case why wouldn't he take a `arr {}interface` at the first place?

Comment: I do not understand this question.